# Finding the function of x in a differential equation $y=f(x)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

If the graph of $y=f(x)$ contains the point $(0,2)$, $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{e^{2x}}{y}$ and $f(x) > 0$ for all $x$, then $f(x) = ?$

$dy/dx = \frac{e^{2x}}y$

$y\cdot  dy = e^{2x}dx$

(The following step confuses me, because of the $dy$).

$\int y\cdot  dy = \int e^{2x}dx$

$\frac{1}2y^2 = \frac{1}2e^{2x}+C$

$y=\sqrt{e^{2x}+2C}$

or

$y=\sqrt{e^{2x}+C}$

from $y(0) = 2$ I get $C = 2^2-e^{2x}$

I can't get to the answer for $f(x) = ?$

Comment: It does not matter : $C$ is a constant, so $2C$ is a constant; just name it $D$. In any manner, whatever you write the value of the constant will be derived from the initial conditions. By the way, when you write $y(0)=2$, $x=0$ in the rhs.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici rhs?

Comment: Sorry ! rhs use to stand for **R** ight **H** and **S** ide.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks. I thought y(x) where y is a function of x, and therefore coordinates 0 = x, 2 = y, would indicate y(0) = 2, where x = 0 and y = 2, no?

Comment: Yes, for sure. When they give you a condition such as $y(a)=b$, it means that when, $x=a$, $y=b$. This is how to determine the value of the constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we have $$\frac{1}{2}y^{2} = \frac{1}{2}e^{2x} + C$$ then $$y = \sqrt{e^{2x}+C'}$$ where $C'=2C$.

For the initial value problem:

$y(0) = 2 = \sqrt{e^{2(0)}+C'} \iff C' = 4 - e^{2(0)} = 4 - 1 = 3$

So $$y(x) = \sqrt{e^{2x} + 3}$$